Modelmapper - Automatic mapping (STRICT Strategy)

[INFO] I've created a sandbox repository to simplify your experience, so you can clone and test it fast.
https://github.com/ImKumin/AutomaticMapping

How can I automatically map models like the ones below with STRICT Strategy?
public class Reward {
    private UserEntity owner; // UserEntity extends Entity which has a .getId()
}

Maps to
public class RewardResponseModel {
    private String ownerId;
}

It WORKS fine if I manually implement this:
Converter<Entity, String> entityToEntityIdConverter = context -> {
    Entity entity = context.getSource();
    return entity != null ? entity.getId() : null;
};

modelMapper.typeMap(Reward.class, RewardResponseModel.class)
        .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(entityToEntityIdConverter)
                .map(Reward::getOwner, RewardResponseModel::setOwnerId));

However, this type of mapping from Entity to String Id, is supposed to be done a lot of times, and I don't want to manually add each mapping like the one above. So I need to generalize a solution. Another example is like this:
private PlayerEntity player; -> private String playerId; // Another example

So basically, something like this pseudo code
modelMapper.typeMap(Object.class, Object.class)
        .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(entityToEntityIdConverter)
                .map(FIND HERE THE get FUNCTION, FIND HERE THE set FUNCTION));

I've tried multiple ways of achieving this with converters and type maps using Reflection, but without success. (Remember that nested classes also need to be mapped)
One of my last tries is here (mostly pseudocode): https://pastebin.com/gy5g5fXa
This seems so doable, but I've been having no luck. Any idea of how I can achieve this?

Do you try config modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STANDARD) ?

Wow, you're actually right. LOOSE and STANDARD actually map what I'm trying to do. Thank you very much. I will keep the question tho, forcing the STRICT strategy because I'm actually curious about a solution.
